# Using Register-ScheduledJob with -ExecutionPolicy parameter

Tags: powershell

I am new to StackOverflow, PowerShell and programming.  I am attempting to register a scheduled job in order to automate running my .ps1 at startup.

Previously, I had successfully used:

```
$action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute 'Powershell.exe' -Argument "-ExecutionPolicy Bypass $dirpath\$scriptname"
$trigger =  New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -AtStartup
Register-ScheduledTask -Action $action -Trigger $trigger -TaskName "my task name" -User SYSTEM -RunLevel Highest
```

This allowed me to verify the action detail/option in the task scheduler.  My script does not execute without passing -ExecutionPolicy Bypass.

New code:

```
$trigger=New-JobTrigger -AtStartup
$options=New-ScheduledJobOption -ContinueIfGoingOnBattery -RunElevated -StartIfOnBattery
Register-ScheduledJob -FilePath $dirpath\$scriptname -ArgumentList "-ExecutionPolicy Bypass $dirpath\$scriptname" -Trigger $trigger -ScheduledJobOption $options -Name "my job name"
```

This does not list my argument in the scheduled tasks GUI, and fails to execute.

I had elected to use Register-ScheduledJob instead for compatibility purposes, as Register-ScheduledTask only seems to work with Windows 8/Server 2012.

Thank you for any guidance provided!

Answer (score 1):

Please check the documentation on [powershell scheduled jobs](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849755.aspx).  A scheduled job is registered in the background, and is not the same thing as a scheduled task.  A scheduled job will not show up in the task scheduler GUI, and is only accessible through powershell.

If you run the `Get-ScheduledJob` command, then you should see your job registered there, and only there will you see it. See this page on [scheduled jobs](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2014/05/12/introduction-to-powershell-scheduled-jobs.aspx)

Comment: Powershell scheduled jobs use the task scheduler.  You can indeed see them in the task scheduler.  Have thoroughly read the documentation and also searched a good bit for examples elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you've got is that you'd need to pass the `-ExecutionPolicy Bypass` into the scheduled job's Action, which I'm not convinced is possible, being as this is populated by the `Register-ScheduledJob` cmdlet itself.  If, like me, you've spent some time unable to work out why the entry isn't working even though you've added it to `-ArgumentList`, this is most-likely why.

The only way I can see to run a PS1 file with `-ExecutionPolicy Bypass` is via `Register-ScheduledTask` and the first example you provided.

Alternatively (and arguably best-practice) would be to sign your PowerShell scripts.